# Is there a simpler way to split list into sublists randomly without repeating elements in python?

Tags: python, list, split

I would like to split a list into 3 sublists (train, validation, test) using pre-defined ratios. The items should be chosen to the sublists randomly and without repetition.
(My first list contains the names of images in a folder which I want to process after the splitting.)
I found a working method, but it seems complicated. I'm curious is there a simpler way to do this?
My method is:

- list the files in the folder,
- define the necessary size of sublists,
- randomly fill in the first sublist,
- remove the used items from the original list,
- randomly fill in the second sublist from the remaining list,
- remove the used items to get the third sublist.

This is my code:

```
import random
import os 

# list files in folder
files = os.listdir("C:/.../my_folder")

# define the size of the sets: ~30% validation, ~20% test, ~50% training (remaining goes to training set)
validation_count = int(0.3 * len(files))
test_count = int(0.2 * len(files))
training_count = len(files) - validation_count - test_count

# randomly choose ~20% of files to test set
test_set = random.sample(files, k = test_count)

# remove already chosen files from original list
files_wo_test_set = [f for f in files if f not in test_set]

# randomly chose ~30% of remaining files to validation set
validation_set = random.sample(files_wo_test_set, k = validation_count)

# the remaining files going into the training set
training_set = [f for f in files_wo_test_set if f not in validation_set]
```

Comment: this seems clean enough to me

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: @mece1390 the op wants a cleaner way of doing it

Comment: What is the meaning of cleaner when he/she says I found a working method but it was complicated?
What element makes it cleaner?
What element makes it complicated?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comments. I already got 2 answers which are more simple and elegant in my opinion, this was my goal. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is self explanatory so I am not adding any explanation.

```
import random
random.shuffle(files)
k = test_count
set1 = files[:k]
set2 = files[k:1.5k]
set3 = files[1.5k:]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking into the sci-kit learn library, as that contains the `train_test_split` function to do this for you. However to answer your question using just the `random` library.

```
# First shuffle the list randomly
files = os.listdir("C:/.../my_folder")
random.shuffle(files) 

# Then just slice
ratio = int(len(files)/5) # 20%
test_set = files[:ratio]
val_set = files[ratio:1.5*ratio] #30%
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help someone. Sklearn has a library that does it easily:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = np.arange(15).reshape((5, 3))
>>> X
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14]])

X_train, X_test =train_test_split(X, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

>>> X_train
array([[ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])

>>> X_test
array([[ 3,  4,  5],
       [12, 13, 14]])
```